# PHP can't use $this as default argument in class method

Tags: php, class, methods, arguments, this

Why cant I do this?

```
class Foo {

    private $val = array(
        'fruit' => 'apple',
        'color' => 'red'
    );

    function __construct( $arg = $this->val['color'] ) {

        echo $arg

    }

}

$bar = Foo;
```

I have also tried this:

```
class Foo {

    private static $val = array(
        'fruit' => 'apple',
        'color' => 'red'
    );

    function __construct( $arg = self::val['color'] ) {

        echo $arg

    }

}

$bar = Foo;
```

I need to be able to provide default values for some of my method arguments from variables already defined within the class.

Comment: If you need to do it that way, your doing it wrong. Please improve your example.

Comment: Use a static variable. What sense does it make to use an object attribute when the object hasn't been constructed yet?

Comment: `$this` doesn't exist when the constructor is called, only after the object has actually been instantiated

Comment: It's not `$this` which is the problem. You can't use *any* expression in func/method declarations. Only constant/literal values.

Comment: Instead of passing `$this->val`, pass `null`. Then check if it's `null`. If it is, pass the private variable.

Comment: Why don't you define these values as class constants rather than properties? Though they'll have to be int/float/string/bool rather than array

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like below;

```
class Foo {

private $val = array(
'fruit' => 'apple',
'color' => 'red'
);

function __construct($arg=null) {

echo ($arg==null) ? $this->val['color'] : $arg;

}

}

$bar = new Foo; // Output 'red'
```

This will echo your default color in $val array defined in class or you can pass the initial $arg value so it will override the default;

```
$bar = new Foo('Yellow'); // Output 'Yellow'
```

Comment: Or even a little smaller `echo ($arg) ? $arg : $this->val['color'];`

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is called when object of that class created and you are trying to pass `$this` in constructor parameter default value so at that $this is not available to your constructor.

`$this` is available only after Constructorget called.

so please try this

```
class Foo {

    private $val = array(
        'fruit' => 'apple',
        'color' => 'red'
    );

    function __construct( $arg = NULL ) {
        echo $arg===NULL?$this->val['color'] : $arg;

    }

}

$bar = Foo;
```